# Cant install package via ansible snap module

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

I just want to do a simple task via **ansible** using **molecule**. The following code below:

```
- name: Continue to install applications
  snap:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    classic: true
  loop:
    - bitwarden
    - clion
```

But I get the following error. With --debug option I didn't get more information

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-19' coro=<_read_stream() done, defined at /home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subprocess_tee/__init__.py:21> exception=ValueError('Separator is found, but chunk is longer than limit')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 540, in readline
    line = await self.readuntil(sep)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 635, in readuntil
    raise exceptions.LimitOverrunError(
asyncio.exceptions.LimitOverrunError: Separator is found, but chunk is longer than limit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/subprocess_tee/__init__.py", line 23, in _read_stream
    line = await stream.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 549, in readline
    raise ValueError(e.args[0])
ValueError: Separator is found, but chunk is longer than limit
CRITICAL Ansible return code was 2, command was: ansible-playbook --diff --inventory....
```

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.10.4
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/vlad/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/vlad/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Molecule version:

```
molecule 3.2.2 using python 3.8 
    ansible:2.10.4
    delegated:3.2.2 from molecule
    vagrant:0.6.1 from molecule_vagrant
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to install snap packages using the `snap` ansible module on Ubuntu `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

Code:

```
---

- name: Playbook for installing required packages
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: Install required packages
    snap:
      classic: yes
      state: present
      name:
        - bitwarden
        - clion
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the machine logs and there was out of memory on a step when ansible trying to install snap in my case

Answer (score 1):

To one who gets the same error in the future. It seems the error is not related to the snap module or any other module. The output will be printed on stdout/stderr and the new line (\n) will be escaped to \\n.
The stream module will try to find b'\n' in the content, but as the new line is escaped, it will not able to find it. So the error will be raised.

As mentioned in the question, the source of error is the asyncio/streams.py module and not ansible itself.

The one way to overcome this issue is by limiting the ansible output by using no_log: true for the task.

The ansible will print the reasonable error message instead of throwing python's error.

```yaml
- name: Check hbase regionserver jmx exporter
  hosts: hbase_regionservers
  tasks:
    - name: Check 'num regions' item
      uri:
        url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname }}:26010/metrics"
        return_content: true
      register: metrics
      no_log: true
      failed_when: metrics.content.find('hbase_regionserver_tables_num_tables 2.0') == -1
```